# How to calculate interpolated values of a 2D function in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have two arrays `X` and `Y` of floats (same length len) and a 2D array `img` (grayscale Image).

I want to calculate the values of `img[X[i]][Y[i]] for i in {0..len}` with a good approximation.

Is it enough to just convert `X` and `Y` to arrays of integers? Or is there a nice interpolation function that gives better results? (I looked for them but there are so many I got confused).

Thanks

Comment: `X` and `Y` are float arrays, which means you can't even use their values as subscripts.

Comment: Well, you can `round` the values, I guess that would be a very good first approach

Answer (score 1):

```py
import scipy.interpolate
y_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
print(y_interp(5.0))
```

`scipy.interpolate.interp1d` does linear interpolation by and can be customized to handle error conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Just using python I would do something like this:

```py
# Calculate tops (just in case the rounding goes over this)
x_top, y_top = len(img) - 1, len(img[0]) - 1
for x, y in zip(map(round, X), map(round, Y)):
    x, y = min(x, x_top), min(y, y_top) # Check tops
    val = img[x][y]  # Here is your value
```

- `map(round, X)` applies the function `round` to each element
- `zip` takes to iterators and returns the elements in pairs